# Printing StackTracein log file

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, logging

I have to use project specific jars for logging which internally uses log4j, in this case logger method which should be used is of below format :

```
        logger.warn(Object object, String method, String text);
```

I want stacktrace to be printed in log file. Can any one please let me know how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Throwable objects have a method for printing their stack trace to a writer.  You could do something like:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(<path to your log file>, true));
someThrowable.printStackTrace(writer);
```

Answer (score 0):

With log4j, there are the following methods which yields the stack strace in the underlying logger:

```
void error(Object message, Throwable t)
void warn(Object message, Throwable t)
void info(Object message, Throwable t)
```

But it seems you are using some kind of specific components built on top of log4j. So, i don't know if they expose the above methods...